# Modificar fechas

Tags: sql

solicito ayuda para modificar las fechas que aparecen en el query, de tal manera que si estan en el mismo rango del mes, solo me aparezca un registro. La idea es hacerlo mediante sql, me podrian ayudar por favor. Muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muestra el código que has intentado

Comment: Tal vez te vendría bien revisar [ask] y realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento de la comunidad.

Comment: --Tabla nueva con los registros incapacidades
SELECT Mes_Novedad, Cedula, Tipo_de_novedad
into #Cedulas
FROM dbo.Ausencias
where Tipo_de_novedad != 'Vacaciones'
and Fecha_Inicio between Fecha_Inicio and Fecha_Fin
group by Cedula, Mes_Novedad, Tipo_de_novedad
having count(Mes_Novedad) > 1
order by Cedula

SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.Cedula ORDER BY a.Cedula ASC) 
AS [ROW] from #Cedulas a
left join dbo.Ausencias b
on a.Cedula = b.Cedula
where b.Tipo_de_novedad = a.Tipo_de_Novedad
and b.Mes_Novedad = a.Mes_Novedad order by a.Cedula

Comment: Primero busco repetidos en la base de datos que tengan la misma novedad en el mismo mes, y luego intento operar con la tabla temporal sobre la base de datos, pero no logro modificar los registros

Comment: por favor, lee los enlaces que te pasaron.. luego de eso, usa el boton [edit] y agrega toda la info en la pregunta... Luego de eso, explica bien que datos tenes, y que datos queres recibir (mostra ejemplos)